# Почему в слове "изжога" корень "изжог", а не жог?

Tags: орфография, однокоренные-слова, морфемный-разбор, корень-слова

И почему для проверки О Е после шипящей в корне нельзя использовать слово **изжечь**?

Для меня общее происхождение этих слов не вызывает сомнений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему в слове *изжога* корень *-изжог-*? По-моему, связь между жжением и изжогой очевидна и актуальна... Поэтому морфемный анализ — из-жог-а. (Кто любит нулевые суффиксы, может учесть это здесь.)

Насчет орфографии: вот что [пишет](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/tbgramota/45_73) Грамота.ру:

> Отдельно необходимо запомнить правило написания слов с корнем ЖОГ / ЖЕГ.
>   Если слово является существительным, то надо писать букву О. Например: СИЛЬНЫЙ ОЖОГ, СОВЕРШЕН ПОДЖОГ ДОМА. Но когда слово является глаголом, оно пишется с буквой Ё. Например: СИЛЬНО ОБЖЁГ РУКУ, НЕИЗВЕСТНЫЙ ПОДЖЁГ ДОМ, АВТОР ЖЖЁТ РУКОПИСИ.

Таким образом, это слово (вообще, гнездо слов с корнем жог/жеч/...) — исключение. С более академическим взглядом можно ознакомиться здесь: http://www.ruslang-oross.ru/article/link/izzhoga1 (это сайт, созданный в Институте русского языка РАН).

Интересное замечание с этого сайта:

> Не путать с глаголом в прош. вр. *изжёг* (что-то): утюг изжёг мне все руки, изжёг все дрова.